# how to write sql query to this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a two table called dbo.name and dbo.class .

name

```
       Name id
        A   1   
        B   2
        C   3
        D   4
```

class

```
     Id     mainid
     1
     2
```

Here I need to fill up mainid by mapping the tables that means suppose if D is a main name and has id 4 that should become mainid in dbo.class. I should get 4 in first row. If c is another main name I should get c’s id as mainid in 2nd row.

```
      2           3
```

how do I write a query for this?please help to write a query for this.

Comment: tried.. but that was not the correct one and later i stuck:-(

Comment: I don't understand how do you fill mainid. Can you explain it with other words? Why does mainid have 4 to Id 1 and 3 to Id 2? How do you know what's a main name?

Comment: main id should be 4 because it has a name D. i need to fill the id of the name D . 4-D,3-C. i need to fill main id...

Comment: What we're trying to get at is that you've got nothing on `class` that points to either D or 4 (or anything else), so how do you know that the class with ID=1 should have a mainid of 4.

Comment: i need to fillup id as mainid in other table

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could post what you have tried even if it does not work. There might be some clues in there to help us understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question exactly.  If the class table is empty and your just looking to populate it from the name table; try this:

```
insert into class (mainid)
select id from name
```

But I'm not sure I totally understand your question.  I think I need a little more information.  Like why you need D to be first?  Is the class table empty and you just need to load it with data from name?  Or is there already data in the class table?

If the class table is empty you can just run the sql I have posted above to load it from the name table.  There is no need to "map" the two tables together.  However, if there is already data in the class table and you don't want to duplicate anything you'd have to run something like the following:

```
insert into class (mainid)
select id from name N
where N.id not in 
    (select distinct (C.mainid) from class C)
```

or a better way to do it:

```
insert into class (mainid)
select id from name N
where not exists (select 1 from class C where N.id = C.mainid)
```

Comment: "fill up mainid by mapping the tables"  By "fill up" do you mean that the class table is empty?  By "map" do you mean that the class table is not empty or may have data in it that you don't want to duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Until you can clearly explain with coherent example, this is the best you can get:

```
SELECT
 dbo.name.id, dbo.class.mainid
FROM
 dbo.name INNER JOIN dbo.class ON dbo.name.id = dbo.class.id
```

And to insert that into a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.newtable 
SELECT
     dbo.name.id, dbo.class.mainid
    FROM
     dbo.name INNER JOIN dbo.class ON dbo.name.id = dbo.class.id
```